# Running multiple instances of the same Target in ant

Tags: ant

Folks,

I need to run multiple instances of the same target in ant.
i.e The deployed ant target should be able to accessible by many users and they should be able to execute the build in parallel.

Regards,
Dhinesh.M

Comment: If you have packed your executable in some jar file & distributed to different users/machine they will be able to run it based on command line you configure to run the target?.

Comment: Any details? What does "deployed ant target" mean? Inside a build file, you can `parallel` some `antcall`s to run the same target at the same time; or you can use `foreach` from ant-contrib if you have a list to process. But I guess you want to run multiple ant builds at the same time, do you?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10130052/how-do-i-stop-jumbling-of-output-from-multiple-ant-tasks-when-using-the-parallel and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158937/can-ant-launch-two-java-applications-concurrently/2180665#2180665

Comment: Thanks. I have a build file in a server / remote machine and I want many users to access it simultaneously. This is my requirement. Do we have any possibility ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible with Client-Server mechanism. It has to be implemented via remoteant where the client invokes the ant target in the server.
By this multiple users can access the same ant file and execute the build.